# how to change time zone in reports

Tags: reporting, oracle-sqldeveloper, bi-publisher

In my application the time zone is (UTC-05:00) New York Eastern Time(ET).while creating report the date field shows 5:30 hr variation.

For example

*Application* **Report**

*sdate 7:30* **1:PM**

I am using BI publisher report.
please any one help me **How to change time zone in BI publisher report**.

I have tried the below steps

Set Preferences-->Regional-->Time Zone(as (UTC+05:30) Calcutta Indian Time(IT)  ).

But I am not able to set time zone for the report.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the time zone in "my account" option.
check this link for more detail.

"https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23943_01/bi.1111/e22257/get_start.htm#BIPUG133"